# Book Involving an Author whose book creations come to life

Tags: story-identification, books

I recall a book I read as a teenager that involved an author whose creations would form up in his attic ( I hope I'm not mixing that part up ). The main Character was a woman I don't know if she was interviewing him or what and the only other part I can remember is a scene where it is a grocery store and a living slice of pizza is causing commotion. It was illustrated I believe because I remember it showing a picture of the slice of pizza with a face arms and legs.

Comment: Roughly speaking, when were you a teenager? When you say "illustrated", do you mean that it was like a children's picture book, or that it had the occasional illustration throughout the book?

Comment: It wasn't a child's book it just occasionally had an illustration. I'd say about 20 years ago maybe.